# Objectie-C - Como eu pego resposta de uma API ao enviar uma mensagem?

Tags: objective-c, mobile

Estou enviando um JSON para uma API. Quando a API recebe um JSON, ela me responde informando se o procedimento teve sucesso ou não.
Como pego esta resposta?

## Código de envio:

```
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.meuSite.com.br/api/listener.php"]];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setValue:@"text/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-type"];
[request setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [_json length]] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-length"];
[request setHTTPBody:[_json dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest: request delegate:self];
```

Answer (score 1):

Através dos seguintes delegates:

```
-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error{
    NSLog(@"did fail");
}

-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data{
    NSLog(@"did receive data");
}

-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response{
    NSLog(@"did receive response ");
}

-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection{
    NSLog(@"did finish loading");
}
```